# Android SQLite DISTINCT query not working with rawQuery()

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I am using `rawQuery()` and `DISTINCT` with SQLite database in my project but query is not working, I receive all results along with repetition. I am using following kotlin function:

```
fun getCompanies(): ArrayList<String> {
    val db: SQLiteDatabase = this.readableDatabase
    val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM customer_cart", null)
    val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    if (cursor.count > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        var count = cursor.count
        while (count > 0) {
            val companyID = cursor.getString(0)
            list.add(companyID)
            count--
            moveToNext()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No item found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are your exact symptoms?

Comment: I mean I get all results, DISTINCT keyword is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, 
                     String[] columns, String selection, 
                     String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, 
                     String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

this is the code in java that I used for using distinct in my query, this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

First problem: you forgot to specify your problem in detail.

Another problem: you're reading the same row over and over again. You need to call `cursor.moveToNext()` to move to the next result row in your loop.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to put `moveToNext()` but main problem is that I receive all results with repetition

Answer (score 1):

use `cursor.moveToNext();`

```
for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
 //do herer
 cursor.moveToNext();
 }
```